# Split VS split up: What's the difference?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Why in the following sentence we use the phrasal "split up" and not "split"?

> The bill for the reconstruction of my mother's house was **split up** into
> several parts: demolition, foundations, east wing and west wing. We
> paid for each part separately on completion.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context there is little or no difference between "split" and "split up".

In general, the phrasal verb has a sense of "completeness". Perhaps if the bill was "split" it would mean one bill had several parts.  If it was "split up", then perhaps one bill was replaced by several separate bills. "Split up" suggests complete separation into parts, and is often used to mean "end a marriage or relationship", or "separate into groups".

> Let's split up. Velma, you go into the crypt with Shaggy and Scooby. I'll explore the vault with Daphne.

And as usual, the phrasal verb tends to be somewhat more informal.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer, James!

Could you give me an example sentence of "split up" with something that doesn't suggest an "end a marriage or relationship", please?

Comment: @Portugueseporto - my wife and I were in the park, searching for our dog which had run off. We decided to split up, with me taking the north side of the park, and her the southern side.

Comment: You already have an example, the one you gave!

Comment: It looks great! Thanks.